# Rewrite URL regular expression

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I would like to rewrite this URL:

```
http://www.mysite/folder/dept/accounting/name.php?id=12
```

to

```
http://www.mysite/folder/dept/accounting/name/12
```

I have found examples of rewriting URLs with .htaccess, but they do not seem to work when the directory in question is not a TLD.

Comment: please post some of the .htaccess directives that you've tried so far.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^name/[0-9][0-9]*$ /name.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: I think you have it backwards in your question... you want the request  `http://www.mysite/folder/dept/accounting/name/12` to go to `http://www.mysite/folder/dept/accounting/name.php?id=12`, correct?

Comment: No, I want id=12 to go to /name/12

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(folder/dept/accounting/name)/(\d+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2
```

Comment: Can I add this to the .htaccess file in /accounting, or does this have to go in the top-level .htaccess file which I do not have access to?

Comment: @John If you add it to `/accounting`, remove all the previous path before it and perhaps try `RewriteBase folder/dept/`.

Comment: @John Can you elaborate more than *doesn't work*? Internal 500 error? No rewriting? Apache error logs?

Comment: No rewriting. It doesn't seem to rewrite /name?id=12 to /name/12. Also, my images and CSS links no longer work when I browse /name/12. Just a blank page.

Comment: @John Put `[R=301]` at the end and see what the URL is being rewritten to (if any).

Comment: It isn't going anywhere. It just displays the name.php page without any CSS or images when I use the convention /name/12 in the URL.

Comment: @John OK, I'm not sure what else to suggest. Are there any rules in ancestor `.htaccess` files or in `httpd.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correct then these rules should work for you in your DOCUMENT_ROOT .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.php$ /$1/%1? [L,NC]
```

This will **internally redirect** a URI of `/folder/dept/accounting/name.php?id=12` to `/folder/dept/accounting/name/12`

And **in case I didn't understand your question correctly** and you actually want opposite of above answer then use this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond  %{QUERY_STRING} !^id= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(\d+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This will **internally redirect** a URI of `/folder/dept/accounting/name/12` to `/folder/dept/accounting/name.php?id=12`.